# match only the number of records on table2 in table1 in Many to many JOIN in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many, left-join

I have a query against two table and the tables have duplicate rows. I want to know if an invoice of a fix amount for a specific customer have been generated and update the status on table1. Problem is there are multiple records with the same  amount for the same customer in table1, so when I run the query all records got updated.

What I'm looking for is: if there are 2 records with the same amounts on table 2 and there are 3 records with the same amounts on table1, it should only update the status of two records that match in table1, it doesn't matter which record is updated.

The data looks like this

Table 1

| CustomerId | Total | serie |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 50 | 113323 |
| 12345 | 50 | 223234 |
| 12345 | 40 | 397867 |
| 12345 | 40 | 766544 |
| 12345 | 40 | 786725 |
| 54321 | 400 | 12346 |
| 54321 | 400 | 32447 |

Table 2

| Customerid | Total | doc# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 40 | 1 |
| 12345 | 40 | 2 |
| 12345 | 50 | 3 |
| 54321 | 400 | 4 |

This is my query right now:

```
select table1.serie, table1.customerid, table1.total,case when count(table2.customerid)/nullif(count(table1.customerid),0)>0 then 'I' else 'NI' end as Status 
from table1 
left join table2 
on table1.customerid=table2.customerid and table1.total=table2.total
GROUP BY table1.customerid, table1.total, table1.serie
```

This is the output I'm getting:

| CustomerId | Total | Status | Serie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 50 | I | 113323 |
| 12345 | 50 | I | 223234 |
| 12345 | 40 | I | 397867 |
| 12345 | 40 | I | 766544 |
| 12345 | 40 | I | 786725 |
| 54321 | 400 | I | 12346 |
| 54321 | 400 | I | 32447 |

This is the output I'm expecting:

| Customerid | Total | Status | Serie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 50 | I | 113323 |
| 12345 | 50 | NI | 223234 |
| 12345 | 40 | I | 397867 |
| 12345 | 40 | I | 766544 |
| 12345 | 40 | NI | 786725 |
| 54321 | 400 | I | 12346 |
| 54321 | 400 | NI | 32447 |

Comment: What is `doc#` and why does it not exist in Table1?

Comment: `count(table2.customerid)/nullif(count(table1.customerid),0)` should be `count(table2.customerid) * 1.0 / nullif(count(table1.customerid), 0)` although it's easier to just do `case when count(table2.customerid) > 0 then 'Paid' else null end as Status` because `count(table1.customerid)` will never be `0` anyway. Unclear what the point of the `GROUP BY` is, and it also seems like a `WHERE EXISTS` might be more sensible, but your requirements are not clear.

Comment: @RyanWilson doc# is the invoice number and it doesn't exists in table1 because in table 1 i only have the customerid with the amounts the customer have to paid every month for each serialnumber.  In table2 i don't have the serialnumber that is why i can't use it. i updates the query with the serialnumber

Comment: @juank Are you sure the serial number in table 1 doesn't match the doc# in table 2? From your updated example, I would assume they are using the serial number to define the invoice number, therefore you can use that in your join.

Comment: @Charlieface i'm sorry there was a column missing in the query. The group by is for customers and serialnumbers. In table1 i have the customersid,serial number and the amount he has to pay every month for each serialnumber. In table2 i have the invoices. Problem is the invoice does not have a serial number attached, so i can only use the customerid and total amount to join the tables. I just mant to know how many invoices have been paid of the total amount in table1.

Comment: @RyanWilson no, they don't match. Invoices only reference to the customersid and amount he paid. I just mant to know how many invoices have been paid of the total amount in table1.

Comment: Matching payments is a question that looks simple but probably isn't. If you don't connect payments to invoices from the start, you're in a lot of pain and should probably fix your data or give up, because it generally won't get better. Also, everything breaks down if part payments are made.

Comment: Here's a little fiddle demonstrating general technique to handle these kind of issues, but as i said, you should fix your data: https://dbfiddle.uk/kdFNlJOg

Comment: @siggemannen I'm sorry i think i phrased the question wrong, im not talking about payments. The table2 have all the invoices that have been generated every month. What i'm looking for is to know when an invoice with a fix amount for a specific customer have been generated. Those invoices have always the same totals for every month. So based on a total of invoices that have to be generate each month (table1) , i can know whats the progress so far. Thanks for the help.